# Using Silverlight DropShadowEffect causes blurring in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am applying the DropShadowEffect in Silverlight 5 on IE9. When the elements are rendered in IE9 they look blurred or out of focus. This is the Effect I am using

```
<DropShadowEffect Direction="274" Opacity="0.5"/>
```

In Firefox 13.0.1 and Chrome 20.0.1132 the control renders as expected with no blurring or softness. Is this a known problem?

Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-Fixing-the-BookShelf-Sample.aspx) is a more general blog post on SL DropShadowEffect performance problems. Maybe it can be of help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue recently with Silverlight in IE causing blurry images (when rendering WritableBitmaps). The fix was actually not a fix, but involved checking the zoom level was 100%!

Note there are also some other IE9 quirks such as blurry text with Silverlight, there is a KB article about it here:

http://techblog.ginktage.com/2011/06/fix-for-internet-explorer-9-on-windows-7-for-blurred-fonts/

Comment: also see this link(http://techblog.ginktage.com/2011/06/fix-for-internet-explorer-9-on-windows-7-for-blurred-fonts/)